# how to get data from two tables using join from my sql table

Tags: mysql, join

I want to get data from two tables using `join`, my tables are

**myLearning** with below given fields:

> user_Name, content_ID, added_Date, status

and **catalog** table

> category, description, title, content_ID

and I need out put as in this format from the both table

> user_Name,description,title where content_ID =?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.user_name, b.description, b.title
FROM    myLearning a
        INNER JOIN catalog b
            ON a.content_ID = b.content_ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Really basic actually:

```
select * from myLearning, catalog where myLearning.content_ID = catalog.content_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  SELECT ml.user_name,cat.description,cat.title 
  FROM mylearning as ml
  LEFT JOIN catalog cat ON cat.content_id=ml.content_id
```

hope it will help!